# initializer-string for array of array of chars is too long

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am making a patcher for a game but I get the error "initializer-string for array of array of chars is too long" from Mingw. I am trying to make a multidimensional array of chars to contain what functions to patch.
I have checked for other questions about this and found one where the asker forgot to add commas to the end of every string literal, but I have done that already.

Could anyone help me?

The source that triggers the error:

```
char patches2[][64] = {
    "CreateMutexW",
    "CreateRemoteThread",
    "CreateRemoteThreadEx",
    "?strcmp@unicode_string_trait@esl@@SAJPB_W0@Z",
    "??0?$CStringT@_WVunicode_string_trait@esl@@Vunicode_string_implement@2@@esl@@QAE@XZ",
    "??0?$CStringT@_WVunicode_string_trait@esl@@Vunicode_string_implement@2@@esl@@QAE@PB_W@Z",
    "??4?$CStringT@_WVunicode_string_trait@esl@@Vunicode_string_implement@2@@esl@@QAEAAV01@PB_W@Z",
    "?GetContent@?$CStringT@_WVunicode_string_trait@esl@@Vunicode_string_implement@2@@esl@@QBEPB_WXZ",
    "?SetLookUpOrder@CFileSystem@esl@@QAEXW4EFileLookUpOrder@esl_constant@2@@Z",
    "??1package_file_item@esl@@QAE@XZ",
    "??1CFormatter@esl@@QAE@XZ",
    "??6CFormatter@esl@@QAEAAV01@K@Z",
    "??6CFormatter@esl@@QAEAAV01@G@Z",
    "??6CFormatter@esl@@QAEAAV01@M@Z",
    "??6CFormatter@esl@@QAEAAV01@PB_W@Z",
    "??BCFormatter@esl@@QBE?AV?$CStringT@_WVunicode_string_trait@esl@@Vunicode_string_implement@2@@1@XZ",
    "?__time@etc@esl@@YAKXZ",
    "?ReadFSAA@CGameOptionMgr@pleione@@QAE?AW4EFSAA@pleione_constant@2@XZ",
    "?ReadFSAAQuality@CGameOptionMgr@pleione@@QAEKXZ",
    "?CleanUp@CPleione@pleione@@QAE_NXZ",
    "?SetSkyTime@CAtmosphere@pleione@@QAEXM@Z",
    "?SetCamera@CCameraControl@pleione@@QAEXPAVCScene@2@PAVITerrain@2@KFF@Z",
    "?GetObjectId@CObject@mint@@QBE_KXZ",
    "?ReadU8@CMessage@mint@@QAEEXZ",
    "?GetLuck@IParameter@core@@QAEMXZ",
    "?GetGateLocalName@CGateMgr@core@@QBE?BV?$CStringT@_WVunicode_string_trait@esl@@Vunicode_string_implement@2@@esl@@AB v34@@Z",
    "?GetLife@IParameterBase2@core@@QAEMXZ",
    "?GetLifeMax@IParameterBase2@core@@QAEMXZ",
    "?IsEiry@SItemEgoInfo@@QBE_NXZ",
    "?SetFog@CDungeonRegion@core@@QAEX_N@Z",
    "?GetTargetCombatPower@ICharacter@core@@QAE?AW4ECombatPower@@PBname2@@Z",
    "?GetCombatPower@IParameterBase2@core@@QBEMXZ",
    "?GetInterfaceDurability@IItem@core@@QBEKXZ",
    "?GetInterfaceDurabilityMax@IItem@core@@QBEKXZ",
    "?GetColor@IItem@core@@QBEKK@Z",
    "?IsElf@ICharacter@core@@QBE_NXZ",
    "?IsGiant@ICharacter@core@@QBE_NXZ",
    "?IsPet@ICharacter@core@@QBE_NXZ",
    "?IsNPC@ICharacter@core@@QBE_NXZ",
    "?IsNamedNPC@ICharacter@core@@QBE_NXZ",
    "?IsGoodNPC@ICharacter@core@@QBE_NXZ",
    "?Compile@CDefaultCompiler@pleione@@UAEPAVCCompiledText@2@ABV?$CStringT@_WVunicode_string_trait@esl@@Vunicode_string_implement@2@@esl@@ABUtext_option@2@@Z",
    "?Compile@CDefaultTagCompiler@pleione@@UAEPAVCCompiledText@2@ABV?$CStringT@_WVunicode_string_trait@esl@@Vunicode_string_implement@2@@esl@@ABUtext_option@2@@Z",
    "?Compile@CHTMLCompiler@pleione@@UAEPAVCCompiledText@2@ABV?$CStringT@_WVunicode_string_trait@esl@@Vunicode_string_implement@2@@esl@@ABUtext_option@2@@Z",
    "?_RenderGlowOverlay@CRendererContext@pleione@@AAEXXZ",
    "?GetExploLevel@IParameterBase2@core@@QBEGXZ",
    "?GetExploExpPercent@IParameter@core@@QBEMXZ",
    "?ParseCommand@CUserConsoleMgr@core@@QBE_NABV?$CStringT@_WVunicode_string_trait@esl@@Vunicode_string_implement@2@@esl@@AAVCUserConsole@2@@Z",
    "?Instance@CLocalizer@core@@SAAAname2@XZ",
    "?GetLocalText@CLocalizer@core@@QBE?AVCFormatter@esl@@ABV?$CStringT@_WVunicode_string_trait@esl@@Vunicode_string_implement@2@@4@@Z",
    "?stdapi_ShowChattingMessage@core@@YAX_KABV?$CStringT@_WVunicode_string_trait@esl@@Vunicode_string_implement@2@@esl@@1KKE@Z",
    "?stdapi_ShowCaption@core@@YAX_KABV?$CStringT@_WVunicode_string_trait@esl@@Vunicode_string_implement@2@@esl@@W4EMessageCaptionType@@KKK0@Z",
    "?stdapi_GetGlobalTime@core@@YA_KXZ",
    "?stdapi_GlobalTimeToGameTime@core@@YAX_KAAK11@Z",
    "?IsUsingNaosSupport@IServiceMgr@core@@QBE_NXZ",
    "?CheckFastStringID@IProp@core@@QBE_NPB_W@Z",
    "?IsUsableContents@IServiceMgr@core@@QBE_NW4EServiceContents@2@@Z",
    "?IsTransformed@ITransformMgr@core@@QBE_NXZ",
    "?GetFullSuitID@ICharacter@core@@QAEKXZ",
    "?IsBroken@IItem@core@@QBE_NXZ",
    "?CheckFastStringID@IItem@core@@QBE_NPB_W@Z",
    "?IsExpired@IItem@core@@QAE_N_K@Z",
    "?IsArenaField@IRegion@core@@QBE?B_NXZ",
    "?CanAttackTarget@IPVPMgr@core@@QBE_NPBVICharacter@2@@Z"
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char patches2[][64]
```

This is an array of arrays.  The first dimension is determined automatically from the number of elements in the initializer.  The second dimension is specified as being 64 `char`s.

Some of the string literals with which you initialize `patches2` are longer than 64 characters in length.  You need to increase the size to some value large enough to hold the largest C string in the initializer.

Comment: Ohhh... I got the two dimensions mixed up Xp

Comment: @kotarou3: then you probably really need an array of pointers to character strings: `char *patches[] = { ... };`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the declaration for a single string looks like this:

```
const char* myString = "MyString";
```

What you probably want is an array of `const char*`s. You can change `char patches2[][64]` to `const char* patches2[]` (an array of pointers to `const char`).

The number of `const char*`s in `patches2` can be calculated using `sizeof()`:

```
const char* patches2[] = {"CreateMutexW", /* The rest... */ };
int numPatches = sizeof(patches2) / sizeof(const char*);
```

So if you add/remove some strings, you don't have to update the dimensions.

Comment: Your answer isn't really an answer to my question, but it's something I can put in :)